# Unable to install the php-posix package on CentOS 5.6

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, php, repository

I have the following PHP packages installed on my CentOS 5.6 host and I am trying to install `php-posix`. When I run `yum install php-posix` I receive an error saying that `php53-common` conflicts with `php-common`.

```
[root@dev ~]# yum list installed | grep php
php.x86_64                               5.3.10-1.w5                   installed
php-cli.x86_64                           5.3.10-1.w5                   installed
php-common.x86_64                        5.3.10-1.w5                   installed
php-devel.x86_64                         5.3.10-1.w5                   installed
php-gd.x86_64                            5.3.10-1.w5                   installed
php-ldap.x86_64                          5.3.10-1.w5                   installed
php-mcrypt.x86_64                        5.3.10-1.w5                   installed
php-mysql.x86_64                         5.3.10-1.w5                   installed
php-pdo.x86_64                           5.3.10-1.w5                   installed
php-pear.noarch                          1:1.9.4-1.w5                  installed
php-soap.x86_64                          5.3.10-1.w5                   installed
php-xml.x86_64                           5.3.10-1.w5                   installed


[root@dev ~]# yum install php-posix
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.krystal.co.uk
 * epel: ftp.uni-koeln.de
 * extras: mirror.krystal.co.uk
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.krystal.co.uk
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53-process.x86_64 0:5.3.3-7.el5_8 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-7.el5_8 for package: php53-process
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-7.el5_8 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: php53-common conflicts php-common
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php53-common-5.3.3-7.el5_8.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> php53-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

What is preventing me from installing `php-posix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been given the solution to this, what I done was this:

```
yum install php-process --enablerepo=webtatic
```

Although, it updated all my PHP packages to 5.3.13

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the `php-common53` package conflicting with installed `php-common` package. The `php-common53` package is version 5.3.3 while the installed `php` packages are 5.3.10. The installed `php` packages may have come from the EPEL or RPMForge repository. You can find out by running `yum info php`.

You will have to remove the `php-common` and dependent packages, and then install `php53-common`. You may lose some of the PHP packages you currently have installed if there is not a counterpart in the repository.

```
# yum remove  php php-cli php-common php-devel php-gd php-ldap php-mcrypt php-mysql php-pdo php-pear php-soap php-xml
```

When you install `php-posix`, the dependent packages such as `php53` and `php53-common` will get installed automatically.

```
# yum install php-posix
```

You should be aware that having either or both EPEL and RPMForge repositories enabled can lead to problems if you aren't careful. Be familiar with the `yum` commands (such as --enablerepo and --disablerepo) and some of the available plugins (yum-plugin-protect-packages and yum-plugin-protectbase) to help manage the software and keep the repositories playing nice.

Comment: I don't really want to have to remove _all_ those packages, just to install `php-posix` that seems like quite an inconvenient way to upgrade one package. I don't want to move all my packages to php53-* either...

Comment: @crmpicco Understandable, but the package version conflicts is what is preventing you from installing php-posix, which answers your question. I did some digging and it appears the php-posix function is included in the package php53-process. No need to install the package php-posix.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too. Same issue though, i'm afraid.

Comment: Ah, well, you may have to downgrade to php53 to get it unless you can find another repository that is compatible. That's a bit of a slipperty slope.

Comment: I've been given the solution to this, what I done was this:

    `yum install php-process --enablerepo=webtatic`

Although, it updated all my PHP packages to 5.3.13 which isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept it so that others with the same issue will know how you resolved it. Also, be vigilant with all those enabled repositories...